# How can I horizontally center a <v-card> in a <v-container>?

Tags: html, css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm making a simple login and register page with VueJS and Vuetify for a personal project but I can't figure out how to horizontally center a v-card I'm using.

I've been looking for a way but the documentation didn't gave any answers and I couldn't find any questions over here so I decided to ask it. Here's my code:

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row class="text-center">
            <v-col cols="12">
                <v-img
                    :src="require('../assets/logo.png')"
                    class="my-3"
                    contain
                    height="200"
                />
            </v-col>

            <v-col cols="12">
                <h1 style="text-align:center">SelliBird</h1>
            </v-col>
            
            <v-container fluid>
                <v-card style="max-width: 50%;" class="elevation-4 mx-auto" dark>
                    <v-card-text class="text-center">
                        <v-col class="mb-4">
                            <h4 style="text-align:center" v-if="options.isLoggingIn">Log in to your customer portal</h4>
                            <h4 style="text-align:center" v-else>Crate a new account</h4>
                        </v-col>
                    </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
            </v-container>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            options:{
                isLoggingIn: true
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And here's a picture of how it looks right now:
[image: The Black box is my v-card]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `margin: 0 auto` to the style property of the v-card and that's it.